# StreamingFileSink doesn't work sometimes when trying to write to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to write to a S3 sink.

```
private static StreamingFileSink<String> createS3SinkFromStaticConfig(
        final Map<String, Properties> applicationProperties
) {
    Properties sinkProperties = applicationProperties.get(SINK_PROPERTIES);
    String s3SinkPath = sinkProperties.getProperty(SINK_S3_PATH_KEY);
    return StreamingFileSink
            .forRowFormat(
                    new Path(s3SinkPath),
                    new SimpleStringEncoder<String>(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
            )
            .build();
}
```

The following code works and I can see the results in S3

```
input.map(value -> { // Parse the JSON
    JsonNode jsonNode = jsonParser.readValue(value, JsonNode.class);
    return new Tuple2<>(jsonNode.get("ticker").asText(), jsonNode.get("price").asDouble());
}).returns(Types.TUPLE(Types.STRING, Types.DOUBLE))
        .keyBy(0) // Logically partition the stream per stock symbol
        .timeWindow(Time.seconds(10), Time.seconds(5)) // Sliding window definition
        .min(1) // Calculate minimum price per stock over the window
        .setParallelism(3) // Set parallelism for the min operator
        .map(value -> value.f0 + ": ----- " + value.f1.toString() + "\n")
        .addSink(createS3SinkFromStaticConfig(applicationProperties));
```

But the following doesn't write anything to S3.

```
KeyedStream<EnrichedMetric, EnrichedMetricKey> input = env.addSource(new EnrichedMetricSource())
        .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                WatermarkStrategy.<EnrichedMetric>forMonotonousTimestamps()
                        .withTimestampAssigner(((event, l) -> event.getEventTime()))
        ).keyBy(new EnrichedMetricKeySelector());

DataStream<String> statsStream = input
        .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
        .process(new PValueStatisticsWindowFunction());

statsStream.addSink(createS3SinkFromStaticConfig(applicationProperties));
```

`PValueStatisticsWindowFunction` is a `ProcessWindowFunction` as below.

```
@Override
public void process(EnrichedMetricKey enrichedMetricKey,
                    Context context,
                    Iterable<EnrichedMetric> in,
                    Collector<String> out) throws Exception {

    int count = 0;
    for (EnrichedMetric m : in) {
        count++;
    }

    out.collect("Count: " + count);
}
```

When I run the Flink app locally, `statsStream.print()` prints the results to `log/flink-*-taskexecutor-*.out`.

In the cluster, I can see checkpoint is enabled and the various checkpoints history from the Flink dashboard. I also made sure the S3 path is in the format `s3a://<bucket>`

Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: First thing to check is that Your data actually has correct timestamps in miliseconds from Epoch and that You have enough data to close the windows, you can also try adding a debug statements  to verify if `WindowProcessFunction` ever gets any data. The second is the `ProcessWIndowFunction` itself, but its hard to say anything if You won't provide the code.

Comment: I have the right timestamps and I can see the watermark advancing. What's puzzling is, the same code works if I run on my localhost with a print() sink.

Comment: Updated with my ProcessWindowFunction impl.

Comment: One more thing, I've thought about, did You enable checkpointing ? This is required for Flink to be able to finalize files and may cause the issue that files are not really appearing in S3.

Comment: Yes, I haven't explicitly enabled it but I can see the checkpointing happening.

Comment: I see the same behavior with a Kinesis data stream sink.

Comment: Hmm, that's really weird. Can You just try to add some log statements to Your process function or check the metrics to be sure that the windows are actually closed properly ? Also, are You certain that the jobs from cluster have properly configures AWS credentials ?

Comment: How does one see the logs in the Flink dashboard?